# In Doctor Sleep what makes the True Knots so dangerous?

Tags: plot-explanation, doctor-sleep

In *Doctor Sleep* I don't get how the True Knots pose such a great threat. They can get killed in normal ways, such as gun fire or crashing a car. Why didn't they involve the police? The True Knots did commit murder and kidnappings, and left behind evidence. Mr.Stone wanted to call the police and FBI but Dan said they are connected and rich since they've been around along time. In the film they do not seem connected or rich. They travel around camping. Even if they were connected and rich they wouldn't get away with abduction and murder.

I guess it could be argued that Abra used her special powers to find True Knots and their victims and she wouldn't be able to explain this to police. But there are anonymous tips to police or some sort of story could be fabricated (e.g. she saw the baseball boy get in the van).

> I guess they got the drop on them, but in the ambush scene Dan and his
>  friend were able to kill 5 True Knots with their guns. The True Knots
>  had guns too and they wouldn't have if they didn't need them.

Also did all of the True Knots have special powers or only some?

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Movies & TV Stack Exchange. You kind of have more than one question in your body and while asking about their powers goes hand in hand with your initial Q, the Q about Billy seems separate and would probably be better as it's own question. Here's a link for to talk a tour of the site:https://movies.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @DarthLocke ok I moved it to a separate question. I do think the question is related though, because normally it's the police who catch dangerous people so Billy must have thought he would better at it than the police. https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/106220/in-doctor-sleep-why-did-billy-attack-the-true-knots

Comment: I can understand that, but Billy's reasoning doesn't necessarily explain WHY they are dangerous, only that he believed he would do better at dealing with them than the police.

Comment: Let's not forget the girl who can tell you what to do. The police would have no defense against that. They wouldn't even be arrested. She could even turn the cops against Danny and his friend. She alone is a significant threat to everyone. Who knows what the rest of the gang can do that they never cover in the film

Comment: @KaiQing no offense but "who knows what else they could do that wasn't shown in the movie" is rather weak reasoning.

Comment: @ChipChell - Tell that to Danny's now dead friend Billy Freeman. Had he held that notion in his mind he may not have come so close to that girl, or by any sane person's logic, may not have gone after them at all.